# In the Bernstein-Vazirani algorithm, what is the use of the second Hadamard gate?

Tags: quantum-circuit, hadamard, bernstein-vazirani-algorithm

In the Bernstein-Vazirani algorithm, what is the use of the second Hadamard gate? What happens if I remove it? Would the algorithm works fine? I read something about it closing the interference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After application of the oracle but before the application of the second Hadamard gates, the register is in the state:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n}}}\sum_{x=0}^{2^n-1} (-1)^{f(x)} |x\rangle.$$

Although the phase $(-1)^{f(x)}$ is correct, the the probability (the squared amplitude) is uniformly distributed over each basis state.  Thus without the second Hadamard gates you would not learning anything about $f(x)$, and your algorithm would not work.

The second Hadamard gates do indeed "close the interference".

Comment: what does close the interference mean?

Comment: I copied that from your question; I'd not heard the term before but it seems like a nice way to say that the second Hadamard gates allow for constructive and destructive interference of the phases.